# What is the cause of the warning: implicit declaration of function 'swprintf_s'?

Tags: c, wchar-t

I am wondering why my use of `swprintf_s` is generating the 
linker warning `warning: implicit declaration of function 'swprintf_s'`

I have this headers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
```

And

```
LPCWSTR foo = L"É %s";
LPCWSTR arg = "bá";
LPCWSTR msg = malloc(wcslen((wchar_t*)foo) + wcslen((wchar_t*)arg) + 1);
swprintf_s(msg, (wchar_t*)foo, (wchar_t*)arg);
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: hrm. According to [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) you should get it with `stdio.h`.

Comment: What version of Visual C++ are you using?

Comment: @Jack - `swprintf_s` is a Microsoft addition, it's not included with GCC or `libc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the `_s` functions (`swprintf_s`, `memcpy_s`) are Microsoft additions.  They are part of Microsoft's C library.  When you use GCC, you will end up using a different C library, which doesn't include Microsoft's additions (but may include its own additions).  Microsoft calls their C library the "CRT" or "C runtime", GCC users refer to it as "libc" or even "glibc" (which is a specific implementation).

If you look at a list of functions in Microsoft's standard C library ([MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/634ca0c2%28v=vs.80%29)), with a sharp eye you'll notice a fairly large number of non-standard functions.  Most of these are part of Microsoft's "security enhancements" ([MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/634ca0c2%28v=vs.80%29)).  In general, I recommend avoiding the security enhancements since they are non-portable and they are not necessary for writing safe code.

**Fix:** You can use `swprintf` instead of `swprintf_s`.  The `swprintf` function is part of the C standard so it is present on many implementations (although it should be avoided on non-Windows platforms, since it uses `wchar_t`).

```
LPCWSTR foo = L"É %s";
LPCWSTR arg = L"bá";
size_t msgbuflen = wcslen(foo) + wcslen(arg) + 1;
LPCWSTR msg = malloc(len);
if (!msg) error...;
swprintf(msg, msgbuflen, foo, arg);
```

Note that `LPCWSTR` is just a fancy typedef for `const wchar_t *`, so you don't need to cast it to `wchar_t *`.